# packard bell easynote te69hw cannot set screen brightness to maximum when charger is not plugged

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, battery, brightness

I just bought a new laptop and there is something that's been annoying me, when am using the laptop with the battery only the screen brightness lower itself automatically, but the problem is that the maximum value of screen brightness also change, on my Acer Aspire the brightness decrease itself too, but i am able to increase it if i want and use the laptop just like the charger is plugged, in the case of Packard Bell i can't, i tried using the FN+Brightness buttons and also tried changing it from windows7 settings, any help please ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Windows 7 from reducing screen brightness when operating on battery?](http://superuser.com/questions/501619/how-to-stop-windows-7-from-reducing-screen-brightness-when-operating-on-battery)

Comment: it's not, his problem is windows changing the brightness from 100% to 60%, in my case it does that and i fixed it, however the 100% brightness when it's plugged is totally different from the 100% brightness when it's unplugged. thank you

Comment: Check also answers in [How to prevent laptop screen brightness from changing when un/plugging battery power](http://superuser.com/q/471073)

Comment: thank you David but all none of the answers is compatible with my issue. I will try and install Win7 Sp1 and see if it solve the issue

Comment: Maybe it is a fault? If the laptop is new try to get it replaced.

Comment: maybe, i'll reinstall the graphic card driver cause in my old Acer i had a similar issue, the screen increase its contrast when its running on battery, reinstalling the integrated graphic card fixed the issue

Comment: Or maybe, DavidPostill, the issue can be resolved by people on this site with actual experience in the matter, which is why the OP posted it in the first place.